# Install Module GroupPolicy in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

i try Install-Module GroupPolicy:

Open a PowerShell prompt (right-click on the PowerShell icon and choose "Run as Administrator").

```
Install-Module -Name GroupPolicy -Force
```

i get error

```
PackageManagement\Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'GroupPolicy'. Try Get-PSRepository to see all available 
registered module repositories.
At C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1809 char:21
+ ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

succeed the command:

```
Import-Module GroupPolicy
```

Comment: There is no such module in the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages?q=GroupPolicy).

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for this module instead:
GroupPolicyDsc

Comment: I still get error @Minkulai

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're looking at the wrong module because "GroupPolicy" doesn't exists. Did you see it somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Install-WindowsFeature GPMC
```

This will install the module files